# How can I add a " Call" button beside "add to cart" button in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem  adding a "Call"  button beside "Add to cart" button on product pages in woocommerce.. I will be happy if someone helps me with a line of code to use. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'my_custom_button');

function my_custom_button(){
?>
Any HTML here
<?php
}
```

Comment: add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'my_custom_button');

function my_custom_button(){
?>
<div class="button-wrapper">
<a class="button cta-button" href= "tel:0200606419">Call to order</a> </div>


<?php
}

Comment: I used this code and I got the result , but am struggling to space between the add to cart button and the call button.  Thank you.